# parse.com how can I test if a column exists in a parse data class iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a persistent store class. classname = Testdata

It has 10 columns.

I want to delete a column via the data browser dashboard. Lets say column 'Test1'.

In my code I want to test for the existence of this column.

ie.

If Testdata.Test1 exists
  do something
else
  do something else

Any help much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PFQuery has a method `whereKeyExists:`

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKeyExists:

whereKeyExists:

Add a constraint that requires a particular key exists.

```
- (void)whereKeyExists:(NSString *)key
```

Parameters:
**key** - The key that should exist.